# SharePoint 2013 sourcedoc

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to embed a OneNote document in a page in SharePoint 2013. I know the code needed to embed an iframe (because SharePoint gives it to you with documents like Word), but the piece I'm missing is the sourcedoc code. I haven't found a way to get this yet--it's not in the properties. Does anyone have an idea of where this number can be found? It looks something like sourcedoc={9c9e3914-cf3a-4c7e-aed9-a3904c7c2291}. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried hovering mouse over the Notebook link from View All Site Content page? I believe it will show the SourceDoc in the URL

Comment: That's it! Thanks! You should put that as an answer so I can get you credit.

Comment: MattCoats - I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hover mouse over the Notebook link from View All Site Content Page.

Then copy the link which will have the SourceDoc query string in the URL